# How to fix 'black background after deletion of one row"

Tags: swift, uitableview

If a row is deleted, tableView shows black area below cells, while tableView has white background color as with the cell view.

Look at this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/55ssb73t0ngr9yj/screenshot.png?dl=0

After deleting a row (it can be any one of them, not necessarily the last one), suddenly, black area shows up, though I didn't change any constraint or height of the tableView. Also, behind tableView, there is nothing in this area other than the 'self.view' whose background is also white, and in front of table view, no view is positioned. (one view is there, but it is the size of the screen, so it cannot be black only for this area.)

```
extension ApptDetailViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return appt.places.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ApptDetailCell", for: indexPath) as! ApptDetailCell
    cell.placeNumLabel.text = "Place \(indexPath.row + 1)"
    cell.placeNameLabel.text = appt.places[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

}

extension ApptDetailViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 60
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {

    let moveString = appt.places.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    let moveBool = appt.reachedPlaces.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)

    appt.places.insert(moveString, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
    appt.reachedPlaces.insert(moveBool, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

    print("appt.places: \(appt.places)")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // deletion occurred.
        appt.places.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        appt.reachedPlaces.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .right)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you look at the view hierarchy debugger, exactly what view is black?

Comment: Wow, that helped me! (I never tried the view hierarchy before...) There is UIButton inside tableView - maybe inserted by mistake... after removing it, it is working fine! Thanks!

Comment: Yep! Use your tools (:

Answer (score 1):

As per our comment discussion —You can debug your UI using the view heirarchy debugger. This helps pinpoint anomalies in your views.

Answer (score 0):

Or try to change the tableview background color.